# how to determine which side causes the intermittent ping failure

Tags: networking, ping

Recently co-workers have been experiencing random connection drop problem with one of the servers. If I ping the server 10 times in a row from my windows client machine,  I can see quite a few  of them fail to get reply back. At this moment I am trying to decide if the problem is in the network between the server and the client machines or in the server itself. My question is, if I can always successfully ping the IP of the server from the server itself, can I say that the cause of the intermittent ping failure from other computers is likely in the network and not in my server?

Comment: Check speed and duplex of the server interface, its values must be the same of the switch port it is connected. A combination of *half-duplex* and *full-duplex* usually cause that behavior. If they are set to *auto detect* or something related,  force them to a value just to be sure they are locked on the same parameters.

Answer (score 1):

One of tool I really like in windows is the tool named `pathping`. In should serve you well for this, as it pings each step along the way, and if there is routing involved, it should nail down the source of the problem.

**Try this:**

From working machine:

```
pathping -n server
pathping -n dodgymachine
```

From dodgy machine:

```
pathping -n server
pathping -n workingmachine
```

From server:

```
pathping -n dodgymachine
pathping -n workingmachine
```

(of course, substitute `dodgymachine`, `workingmachine`, and `server` with the actual IPs. I've included the `-n` switch, as doing lookups is probably not necessary).

Yes, there is some redundancy with running them both ways between all of those nodes, but being thorough never hurt anyone[citation needed].

What it does is basically the same thing, but it does so for any hops in between over some time (usually 10 minutes, if I remember correctly), and builds some statistics. If you run all of the above, you should be able to compare results.